# How to send PNG data response received from REST Api

Tags: javascript, node.js, image

I'm calling an API from Node.JS which results PNG data in response body, I'm getting response in encoded format (image attached below):

[image]

Now I need to send this PNG image as response in my API.

I'm able to save the image with below snippet:

```
const writer = fs.createWriteStream("testimage.png");

        const streamResponse = await axios({
          'method': 'GET',
          responseType: 'stream',
          'url': endPoint + requestRoute,
          'headers': {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + _token 
          }
        });

        streamResponse.data.pipe(writer);
```

But I don't want to save image in my server, I want to send the image received from external API on the fly as response in my API.

Example:

```
Api.getPNGImage = async function (_request, _respsonse) {

    var options = {
        'method': 'GET',
        'url': endPoint + requestRoute,

        'headers': {
            'content-type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + _token
         }
};
 request(options, function (error, response) {
        let image = response.body;
        _respsonse.send(image)
    });
}
```

I tried below approach, but base64 comes out invalid:
`let str = "data:" + 'image/png' + ";base64," + Buffer.from(_responses.body).toString('base64');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly pipe the stream response to the client response. This approach avoids the need to save the image on your server and allows you to forward the image data directly to the client.

1. Ensure you set the correct `Content-Type` header in the response to inform the client that it's receiving an image.
2. Use the [stream.pipeline](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/node-js-stream-pipeline-method/) method to handle the streaming of data from the external API to the client response. This method automatically handles cleanup of resources and error handling.

```js
const axios = require('axios');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const stream = require('stream');

app.get('/your-route', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const streamResponse = await axios({
            method: 'GET',
            responseType: 'stream',
            url: endPoint + requestRoute,,
            headers: {
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + _token 
            }
        });

        // Set the Content-Type header to image/png
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'image/png');

        // Use stream.pipeline to handle the streaming of data
        await stream.pipeline(
            streamResponse.data,
            res,
            (err) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.error('Pipeline failed.', err);
                    res.status(500).send('Streaming failed.');
                }
            }
        );
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Request to external API failed.', error);
        res.status(500).send('Request to external API failed.');
    }
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Server is running on port 3000');
});
```